# I have two unopened bags of LEGO, I can’t figure out what set they're from

Tags: set-identification

Two bags from Goodwill, bags are marked 2017, number 135149 (which I’ve heard is not useful information anyway)... The QR code unfortunately would not work on the LEGO app.

[image: eded]

[image: doo]

[image: ws]

[image: kl]

[image: op]

Answer (score 6):

These are parts from

[31091: Shuttle Transporter](https://brickset.com/sets/31091-1/Shuttle-Transporter)

[image]

Keyparts

- [Wedge, Plate 6 x 6 Cut Corner](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6106&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)
- [Tile, Modified 2 x 3 with 2 Open O Clips](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30350b&idColor=15#T=C&C=15)

Comment: Bagnumber matches too. I just checked with my own set. I still happened to have the bags in the recycle bin. (Got the set last week and build it Sunday. Didn't empty the bin yet.)

Answer (score 4):

According to BrickLink, the only set with [White Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=44728&colorID=1&in=A) and [Light Bluish Gray Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Flutes (Grille) and Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=92947&colorID=86&in=A) and [White Slope, Curved 2 x 1 x 1 1/3 with Recessed Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6091&colorID=1&in=A) is [31091 Shuttle Transporter](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=31091-1). It also seems to have the pieces from the second bag.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's the set with the boat/ocean liner from 2017. We just found an unopened bag of the crane on the back of the ship from that set. (Bag#2 from set?)

Comment: Do you mean [42064 Ocean Explorer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42064-1)? From the other answers it looks like these parts are from set 31091.